# How to iterate through nested map of JSON in groovy

Tags: json, groovy, iteration

I have below JSON output from AWS DynamoDB and I want to iterate through it and populate the table in Jenkins Parameters through groovy script. Is it possible to do?

**JSON:**

```
[
    {
        "test": {
            "S": "0"
        },
        "dev": {
            "S": "1"
        },
        "cert": {
            "S": "2"
        },
        "prod": {
            "S": "3"
        }
    }
]
```

I tried to iterate through the list and I could not get the value from `"S": "1"`

**Groovy Code:**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''
    [
      {
        "test": {
            "S": "0"
        },
        "dev": {
            "S": "1"
        },
        "cert": {
            "S": "2"
        },
        "prod": {
            "S": "-3"
        }
    }
  ]
'''

def json_out = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

json_out.each{ key, value ->
    value.each {k, v ->
      println "${key}"
        println "${v}"
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 3: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 3, column 15.
           "test: {
                 ^
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The snippet marked as "Groovy Code" isn't how you make an immediate map in Groovy, and it's not JSON (JSON is a string).

Comment: actually that is the output I get from AWS DynamoDB command so I just pasted there. I have updated the groovy code

Comment: What's line 3, column 15? It doesn't align w/ the code if it's in a big string.

Comment: ```"test": {``` this is line 3 and it is expecting '}'. I guess iteration is wrong

Comment: It's a multi-line string; it doesn't "expect" anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is a list of objects:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def myMaps = '''
[
    {
        "test": {
            "S": "0"
        },
        "dev": {
            "S": "1"
        },
        "cert": {
            "S": "2"
        },
        "prod": {
            "S": "3"
        }
    }
]
'''

def jsonMap = new JsonSlurper().parseText(myMaps)

jsonMap.each { obj ->
    obj.each { key, value ->
        println key
        println value.S
    }
}
```